# Json Ajax Parameter pass & Webmethod not firing

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

In my Ajax function i tried to pass a int Parameter to the Webmethod but it's not success.
Here  i paste my code

Ajax Function

```
    $('#drpChurchNames').on('change', function () {
        //alert($(this).val());
        LoadFathersToChurch(churchId)
    });

    function LoadFathersToChurch(churchId) {

        var url = '<%=ResolveUrl("WebMethods.aspx/GetFatherNames") %>';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data:'{ Id: " '+churchId +' "}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (Result) {
                $.each(Result.d, function (key, value) {
                    $("#drprevfather").append($("<option></option>").val
                    (value.Id).html(value.FatherName));
                });
            },
            error: function (e, x) {
                alert(x.ResponseText);
            }
        });

    }
```

Here is my WebMethod

```
      [WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
 public static List<FatherNames> GetFatherNames(int ChurchId)
 {
     List<FatherNames> FathersList = new List<FatherNames>();
     try
     {
         SqlCommand comChurchNames = new SqlCommand("GetFathers", conDB);
         comChurchNames.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         comChurchNames.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
        comChurchNames.Parameters["@Id"].Value = ChurchId;
        if (conDB.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conDB.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = comChurchNames.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(rdr);
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            FathersList.Add(new FatherNames
            {
                Id = (int)r["Id"],
                FatherName = r["FatherName"].ToString()

            });
        }
    }
```

Here is my SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFathers]
@SelectIndexName int
AS
BEGIN
Select * from dbo.RevFathers
Where ChurchId = @SelectIndexName
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `Id` as parameter and the correct is `ChurchId` just like webmethod signature `GetFatherNames(int ChurchId)`.

There is the correct way:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data:'{ ChurchId: " '+churchId +' "}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (Result) {
            $.each(Result.d, function (key, value) {
                $("#drprevfather").append($("<option></option>").val
                (value.Id).html(value.FatherName));
            });
        },
        error: function (e, x) {
            alert(x.ResponseText);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your webmethod actually getting executed? If it is and you think it should be returning data, it could be that your webmethod is not returning JSON, thus jQuery may be generating and error and not firing success.

I have this in my global.asax to configure the output for both XML and JSON:

```
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http;
```

Placed in app_start

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new QueryStringMapping("type", "json", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")));
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new QueryStringMapping("type", "xml", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml")));
```

I know this isn't a direct answer, but I can't post comments yet so I would have just asked the above question first about is the webmthod getting called.